# Call playlist content from sql database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, schedule, playlist

I have an sql database with an hourly playlist schedule which includes title, host and timeslot (1:00pm - 3:00pm etc). I want to call that playlist into a div and highlight what's playing based on the actual current time. How do I do this in php?

The schedule is weekly (Mon - Sun) but repeats, so the database will never change. I need it to cycle through and display what's playing at what time/day correctly (the date doesn't matter).

I plan on designing a 7 day list, with tabs for Monday, Tuesday etc outlining all the playlist content. Each days tab displays that days playlist when clicked by the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an SQL dump of your database structure, with some simple data, and what you have tried so far with PHP ?

Comment: Also, have you tried to find some PHP code dealing with playlist on the web (not older than 4-5 years old)? This might be a good starting point.

Comment: this is not a free write-my-code service. What have you researched and tried so far? What precisely are you stuck with? There are a few different steps involved in this - fetching data, reading it, formatting it, detecting what's playing, formatting that. What part is giving you a problem, exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I'm researching now about the playlist in php. It is not easy. Basically everything after calling the database is what I'm stuck on now. I understand if it's too difficult to answer in reasonable amount of text.

Comment: maybe you need to take some tutorials on PHP / HTML / CSS then, if you're stuck with the very basics. It's too much for an answer on here, yes

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. It was not easy and had to get someone else to do that particular part of the website. Essentially we imported the sql data from the old database into a new one and then created custom code with php to access the new data.